# ios 6 multiple pages in popover

Tags: ios, ios6, uipopover

I want to create a view that has a button in the top bar that provides a popover with a list of choices, say a tableView, and when the user selects an item the popover has a flip transition to a secondary set of choices.  The first set would be like categories, and the second set would be the actual choices to display.

What would be the best approach to this situation?  I'm rather new to iOS development.  I can get a popover, but I'm not sure how to get that flip transition to another table in the same popover.

Also if anybody believes this to be a poor User Interface design, I'm all ears for any suggestions in which would accomplish the same functionality.  Like I said, I'm new to this and I'm still learning the better UI designs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your UITableView as a presented viewcontroller and have it presrnt the second view controller.

Comment: are you meaning the view I make for the popover has a segue to another view? or programmatically have it call the second view?  I'm assuming the best approach would be to programmatically create/call it that way it gets populated with all the correct information without having to deal with a custom segue.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an action sheet which gives the user a choice to which new view they want to go to (flip to). It is clean and simple to execute, and an action sheet is quite common and iPhone users are comfortable using them.